# Правильно выбранный селектор для .map

Tags: javascript

Не вполне понимаю механику селекторов в js. Есть таблица

```
<table>
  <tr value="..." style="background-color: lightgreen;">...</tr>
  <tr value="...">...</tr>
  <tr value="..." style="background-color: lightgreen;">...</tr>
  <tr value="...">...</tr>
  <tr value="...">...</tr>
  <tr value="...">...</tr>
</table>
```

Есть константа

```
const rStrings = [...document.querySelectorAll('tr[value]')]
  .map(tr => tr.getAttribute('value'));
```

Но она даст вообще все значения в tr тегах. Как выбрать только те, что подкрашены светло-зеленым?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const rStrings = [...document.querySelectorAll('tr[value][style="background-color: lightgreen;"]')]
```

Но лучше:

```
const rStrings = [...document.querySelectorAll('tr.colored[value]')]

.colored {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

<tr value="..." class="colored">...</tr>
<tr value="...">...</tr>
```

Comment: Дело в том, что я собираю именно value в массив. И так выходит, что `const rStrings = [...document.querySelectorAll('tr[value]')].map(tr => tr.getAttribute('value'));` работает (но попадают все value), а `const rStrings = [...document.querySelectorAll('tr[value][style="background-color: lightgreen"]')].map(tr => tr.getAttribute('value'));` оставляет массив почему-то пустым...

Comment: А, понял. Не хватало точки с запятой в значении аттрибута style.